# Integrate Leaflet / OpenStreetMap autocomplete functionality to an existing search form on a WordPress template

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, geocoding, wordpress

I am trying to add the autocomplete functionality similar to what you have here https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#advanced to the search form in my website. Unfortunately there are no pre-existing plugins for Leaflet https://leafletjs.com/ & OpenStreetMap maps integrations like you have for Google Places autocomplete for WordPress templates.

Is there an easy way of integrating in existing template searchforms like you have in the examples here?

- [Leaflet address search/geocoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290799/leaflet-address-search-geocoding)
- http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/geocoding-control.html

Looking for some suggestions.

The page I need to change: http://demo.ohmyproperty.com/

Comment: The internet lists various examples for using Leaflet with Nominatim or Photon (the latter supports autocompletion). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @scai I ended up using a openstreet/leaflet.js based map provider ->  https://github.com/location-iq/leaflet-geocoder which gives 10k request per day access to their API if you are on their free plan. Unless of course your suggestions above will provide the same absolutely for free ..

Comment: I didn't suggest a particular Nominatim instance since your question is not about finding a particular [location provider](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) but about integrating Nominatim in general. You should be able to configure any existing Leaflet+Nominatim/Photon solution to use LocationIQ as location provider.

Comment: @scai Just to make things clear, I finally settled on locationIQ as my location provider and used their autocomplete feature .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used both the location provider and Autocomplete API provided by https://github.com/location-iq/leaflet-geocoder. This autocomplete feature utilises a Search API that returns place predictions in response to an HTTP request. The request specifies a textual search string and optional geographic bounds and works as expected.